# FadeIn stops working when delayed in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay, fadein

I want to add .delay() to this, so each item will animate one after the other. The problem is that if I add delay() to the element the fadeIn stops working.

Working code (but without delay...)

```
time = 500;

for (var i=1;i<=5;i++){

    delay2 = (i * time);
    $('<tr><td><h3>Hello</h3></td><td>'+i+'</td</tr>').hide().appendTo('#table').fadeIn("slow").css('display', 'table-row');

    // do more stuff here

};
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/pYYFM/4/)

FadeIn not working (as it has delay...)

```
time = 500;

for (var i=1;i<=5;i++){

    delay2 = (i * time);
    $('<tr><td><h3>Hello</h3></td><td>'+i+'</td</tr>').hide().appendTo('#table').delay(delay2).fadeIn("slow").css('display', 'table-row');

    // do more stuff here

};
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/u5dEp/2/)

Does anyone know what is the problem? In the second example it should animate the items one after te other, but that does not happen, they're not even animated.

Comment: "+i+'</td</tr>')" see the missiing closing tag of td

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('<tr><td><h3>Hello</h3></td><td>'+i+'</td</tr>')
.appendTo('#table')
.hide()
.delay(delay2)
.show('slow');
```

The problem here is that the css change occurs instantly, whereas you want it to occur after the fade in is complete. You do not need `fadeIn` at all here, especially since `show` will remember the `display` attribute value and restore it automatically.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u5dEp/7/

Comment: Yours is correct as well, so I could have accepted yours perfectly, but the other user put more effort and made a fiddle so I had to give it to him

Comment: @Tebb I have made a version that works according to your requirements (I noticed the others were still incomplete solutions). Have a look at the fiddle above.

Comment: Works perfectly ^^. I also made it work using `.addClass("dontshow")` instead of `.hide()`, `.dontshow { display:none; }`

Answer (score 3):

Your answer:

```
$('<tr><td><h3>Hello</h3></td><td>'+i+'</td</tr>')
.hide()
.appendTo('#table')
.delay(delay2)
.fadeIn("slow")
.queue(function() { $(this).css('display', 'table-row'); });
```

The explanation is simple: when you chain events that go in the queue and events that do not go in the queue, the events that do not go in the queue will bypass it. $.css() does not go in the fx queue, so will be executed immediately.

The solution to this is to use the $.queue() function to queue your non-queueable calls into the fx queue.

**Working fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/u5dEp/6/

(That's a lot of queues in one answer)

Comment: Thanks it works, but now the CSS change is made after the fade in so you can notice how it goes from css display:block (added by fadeIn effect) to display:table-row. Any way to fix this? Looks bad.

Comment: You (sadly) have to have a container of either inline, inline-block or block to use the opacity property. table-rows cannot be faded in any other way :-(

Comment: That typo was very, very well hidden. However, his code does not "fix" the issue on chrome.

Answer (score 1):

even this can work: http://jsfiddle.net/pYYFM/8/

```
time = 500;

for (var i=1;i<=5;i++){

delay2 = (i * time);
    $('<tr><td><h3>Hello</h3></td><td>'+i+'</td></tr>').hide().appendTo('#table').delay(delay2).fadeIn("slow").queue();
                                               ^-------missed this
};​
```

Comment: This is the best solution as it fixes the display:table-row aswell.

Comment: That doesn't display the rows correctly (at least in Firefox). The `tr`s are rendered with `display:block`.

Comment: Ah you're right, it's weird but in his fiddle it looked good.